# Sort a data frame column based on another txt file

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a txt file of transcripts ids (transcripts) and a dataframe (t2g) with 3 columns (transcripts ids, gene ids, gene symbols), they have the same length.

```
> head(transcripts)
                     V1
1  ENSMUST00000000266.8
2 ENSMUST00000000514.10
3  ENSMUST00000000834.3
4  ENSMUST00000001027.6
5 ENSMUST00000001166.13
6 ENSMUST00000001171.12

> head(t2g)
                    V1                   V2            V3
1 ENSMUST00000001171.12 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
2 ENSMUST00000001027.6 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
3 ENSMUST00000000834.3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
4 ENSMUST00000000266.8 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
5 ENSMUST00000000514.10 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
6 ENSMUST00000001166.13 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956
```

I'd need the data frame ordered as the txt file, that cannot be sorted.

I started in R by renaming dataframe rownames as the transcripts in the txt file

```
> vector <- transcripts[,1]
> rownames(t2g) <- vector 
> head(t2g)
                                        V1                   V2            V3
ENSMUST00000000266.8  ENSMUST00000001171.12 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
ENSMUST00000000514.10 ENSMUST00000001027.6 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
ENSMUST00000000834.3  ENSMUST00000000834.3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
ENSMUST00000001027.6  ENSMUST00000000266.8 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
ENSMUST00000001166.13 ENSMUST00000000514.10 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
ENSMUST00000001171.12 ENSMUST00000001166.13 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956
```

But I don't know how to move forward from here. Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Your output can be mimicked with `cbind(transcripts, t2g)`. You could also just do `t2g$transcript <- transcripts$V1`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. These two methods only add an extra column to the data frame but they don't change the order of the other columns. I need all the columns to be re-ordered based on the transcripts.txt file

Comment: I admit that I have *absolutely no idea* what you need. You said *"ordered as the txt file"*, but since there are not matching elements, then discussing order in this fashion seems meaningless. Your suggested output has done nothing to the sort order either. Please update your sample data to provide clarity.

Comment: You're right, I uploaded only the head of the files so it's not clear at all. Transcript names are the same in the 2 files. Updated now

Comment: Are the transcript IDs unique?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the IDs are unique, we can use `match`:

```
t2g[match(transcripts[[1]], t2g[[1]]), ]
#                      V1                   V2            V3
# 4  ENSMUST00000000266.8 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 5 ENSMUST00000000514.10 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 3  ENSMUST00000000834.3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 2  ENSMUST00000001027.6 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
# 6 ENSMUST00000001166.13 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956
# 1 ENSMUST00000001171.12 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
```

Using this data:

```
transcripts = read.table(text = '                     V1
1  ENSMUST00000000266.8
2 ENSMUST00000000514.10
3  ENSMUST00000000834.3
4  ENSMUST00000001027.6
5 ENSMUST00000001166.13
6 ENSMUST00000001171.12', header = T)

t2g = read.table(text = '                    V1                   V2            V3
1 ENSMUST00000001171.12 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
2 ENSMUST00000001027.6 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
3 ENSMUST00000000834.3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
4 ENSMUST00000000266.8 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
5 ENSMUST00000000514.10 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
6 ENSMUST00000001166.13 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956', header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `merge` the data

**EDIT**: as @GregorThomas corrected me, `base::merge` sorts the data by default. Adding `sort=FALSE` should correct that.

```r
merge(transcripts, t2g, by = "V1", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
#                      V1                   V2            V3
# 1  ENSMUST00000000266.8 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 2 ENSMUST00000000514.10 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 3  ENSMUST00000000834.3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 4  ENSMUST00000001027.6 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
# 5 ENSMUST00000001166.13 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956
# 6 ENSMUST00000001171.12 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
```

Something to look out for is `NA` in columns (other than `V1`).

- if a `V1` exists in `transcripts` but not in `t2g`, then all of the other (non-`V1`) `t2g` columns will be `NA`;
- if a `V1` exists in `t2g` but not in `transcripts`, then all of the other (non-`V1`) `transcripts` columns will be `NA`. Granted, in this case there are no other columns, so this will not be an issue.

The number of rows returned will be no less than the number of rows in either of the frames. It will be greater if there are any rows in one and not the other.

This is what is known as a "full join" between two frames/tables. There are two good links for learning about the different types of joins:

- [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) gives a good description of each;
- and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272 gives good venn-diagram pictures

In short:

- "left join" preserves all rows from the left-hand side (LHS), which in this case is `transcripts` (the first of the two frames merged); rows in the RHS frame that do not match any of the `by` elements in the LHS will be dropped; if the matches are at most 1-to-1 (meaning there are no duplicate ids in the second frame), then this will produce the same number of rows in the output as the LHS frame; if there are duplicate ids in the RHS, then the number of rows will increase;
- "right join" similar, but reverse LHS/RHS;
- "full join" preserves all rows from both sides; this should never produce fewer rows than the longest frame
- (there are several more types)

---

Demonstration of GregorThomas's point about `merge(..., sort)`.

First, change the order, where I swap rows 3-4:

```r
transcripts <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                     V1 V2
1  ENSMUST00000000266.8  1
2 ENSMUST00000000514.10  2
4  ENSMUST00000001027.6  4
3  ENSMUST00000000834.3  3
5 ENSMUST00000001166.13 5
6 ENSMUST00000001171.12  6", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Now the two merges, one with the default of `sort=TRUE` (implied), one not sorted.

```r
merge(transcripts, t2g, by = "V1", all = TRUE)
#                      V1 V2.x                 V2.y            V3
# 1  ENSMUST00000000266.8    1 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 2 ENSMUST00000000514.10    2 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 3  ENSMUST00000000834.3    3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 4  ENSMUST00000001027.6    4 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
# 5 ENSMUST00000001166.13    5 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956
# 6 ENSMUST00000001171.12    6 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
merge(transcripts, t2g, by = "V1", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
#                      V1 V2.x                 V2.y            V3
# 1  ENSMUST00000000266.8    1 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 2 ENSMUST00000000514.10    2 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 3  ENSMUST00000001027.6    4 ENSMUSG00000064842.1       Gm26206
# 4  ENSMUST00000000834.3    3 ENSMUSG00000051951.5          Xkr4
# 5 ENSMUST00000001166.13    5 ENSMUSG00000102851.1       Gm18956
# 6 ENSMUST00000001171.12    6 ENSMUSG00000102693.1 4933401J01Rik
```

The second shows my expected output. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this will actually `sort` the columns, lexicograhically, not preserve the order in `transcripts`? So I think (assuming all IDs have matches) this is equivalent to `t2g[order(t2g$V1), ]`?

Comment: This use of `merge` produces a left-join, which should preserve the order of the LHS. Unless I'm mistaken, doesn't left-join ensure the order and row-presence of the LHS? I've always assumed it does, and haven't *seen* warnings/errors that would result from this assumption being wrong.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I meant "full join", but it should hold true for left joins too.

Comment: Yes the ids are unique. Something is wrong with `merge` because my output is simply sorted numerically. `match` works just fine! Thank you!!

Comment: I don't know what is happening with the sort.

Comment: I think the `dplyr` join functions are good about preserving order, but `?base::merge` says *"The rows are by default lexicographically sorted on the common columns, but for `sort = FALSE` are in an unspecified order."* I remember this as a big annoyance with `merge` years ago when I first started using `ggmap` - merging geo shape data with other data with `merge` would mess up the plots unless you added an ID column first to sort by at the end. In the early releases of `dplyr` their fidelity to the original data order was touted as an advantage over `merge`.

Comment: Oh man, great point @GregorThomas, I've been using `dplyr::*_join` and otherwise explicitly sorting elsewhere that I had forgotten that point. But I recall it now, and you are absolutely right. I need to practice what I preach more (rtfm). Thanks for the correction!